# libpam-google-authenticator failing on kubuntu 23.04 (seemingly due to polkitd)

Tags: pam, authentication, 2-factor-authentication

I have used libpam-google-authenticator for several years. I always set it up to require a password + TOTP token as the password in pam.  I type in my password, and then press the button on my "onlykey" that types in a TOTP token and hits enter.  Painless and a bit more secure.  SSH is obviously using RSA, but all other logins: X, physical terminal, sudo, etc require password + TOKEN.   This worked flawlessly for previous installs.  Now however, it is failing mysteriously.  After reviewing the source code on github, I have a notion it might be something to do with the host coming in as null in several instances of code that adjusts time skew and attempts to stop replays.

Right after setup, everything seemed to be working, but as we go several days on, the TOTP token is failing every time.  I have done the following:

- Check in real time that the server date/time matches pool.ntp.org
- Manually calculated the TOTP using oathtool and comparing the only key output (oathtool -b --totp "SECRET" for those interested)

I can see in every instance that the time is correct and that the TOTP is correct, but the google authenticator declares it incorrect.

I wanted to get this question out here to see if anyone else has seen this.  For now, my next course of action is to see if a reboot changes anything.  And if that works, then I would need to see what services need to be restarted.

EDIT:

Rebooting would be painful, and I am lazy, so I ran systemctl and found this:

```
polkit.service                                                                           loaded active     running   Authorization Manager
```

restarting that service, and it now works again.  So we have a workaround.  Is there an answer out there?